chrome web store developers dashboard uploading error
While i'm trying to upload my extension evry time showing up problem "There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.". And under the error there is tip "Enabling 2 step verification on your account is required for security purposes.". I'm already enable 2 step verification, but the error popup evry time i'm trying to upload, how can i fix this ?
my manifest:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "*NAME*",
  "version": "1.6",
  "description": "*DESCRIPTION*",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "scripting", "declarativeContent"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon.png",
    "48": "img/icon.png",
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*LINK*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}


I was trying already to clean cookies, going to incognito mode, switched device but nothing helping :(

go here : https://myaccount.google.com/security
scroll down go to this tab
How you sign in to Google
find 2fa you may already added phone but turn on from here add authenticator app also

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
